# Read .xlsx file when the file is opened using php

Tags: php, xlsx

I need to read the data from the .xlsx file when that file is opened without saving it.

The .xlsx file is frequently updating (in every 1 or 2 seconds), so I need last updated data from the file.

```
<?php

include 'xls/simplexlsx.class.php';
$xlsx = new SimpleXLSX('export_data.xlsx');
$xlxs_value = $xlsx->rows();
echo $xlxs_value;

?>
```

But when I executed this code, I get data only when the file is last saved, so please help me to read the data without saving the file and it is opened by MS OFFICE.

Comment: Maybe transferring the data through an Excel file isn't the way to go about this. When the user makes changes to the file, the changes are in memory on the users computer. It's not until they save that the server file that you're reading gets updated. You're always going to be a step behind what the inputters have on their screen in Office.

Comment: The answer might be a browser-based data input screen.